# How to add a caption in a long table

Tags: longtable

I tried to create a longtable but it does not really work. I have two problems:

1. The table is created in the following page (I tried to solve this with the longtable package but it does not seem to work).
2. The caption of the longtable appears in a strange location.

Please find attached my code and the result of it. I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me with this!

```
\begin{longtable}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5em}}{Scenario} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Deterministic T. Costs (\euro M)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Stochastic  T. Costs (\euro M)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference (\euro M)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5em}}{Scenario} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Deterministic T. Costs (\euro M)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Stochastic  T. Costs (\euro M)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference (\euro M)}} \\
    \hline
    \textit{1} & 436,05 & 433,99 & \textbf{-2,06} & \textit{51} & 435,59 & 433,18 & \textbf{-2,41} \\
    \textit{2} & 437,30 & 437,71 & \textbf{0,40} & \textit{52} & 431,33 & 430,24 & \textbf{-1,10} \\
    \textit{3} & 429,85 & 430,49 & \textbf{0,65} & \textit{53} & 440,37 & 437,46 & \textbf{-2,91} \\
    \textit{4} & 426,31 & 426,69 & \textbf{0,38} & \textit{54} & 430,01 & 426,55 & \textbf{-3,46} \\
    \textit{5} & 432,58 & 432,10 & \textbf{-0,47} & \textit{55} & 431,33 & 429,88 & \textbf{-1,45} \\
    \textit{6} & 439,02 & 436,87 & \textbf{-2,15} & \textit{56} & 429,63 & 427,40 & \textbf{-2,23} \\
    \textit{7} & 418,62 & 420,74 & \textbf{2,12} & \textit{57} & 432,96 & 430,70 & \textbf{-2,26} \\
    \textit{8} & 443,74 & 441,88 & \textbf{-1,85} & \textit{58} & 431,46 & 431,27 & \textbf{-0,19} \\
    \textit{9} & 430,93 & 429,14 & \textbf{-1,79} & \textit{59} & 421,42 & 422,11 & \textbf{0,69} \\
    \textit{10} & 425,81 & 424,64 & \textbf{-1,16} & \textit{60} & 417,78 & 419,35 & \textbf{1,57} \\
    \textit{11} & 420,18 & 422,59 & \textbf{2,41} & \textit{61} & 437,42 & 434,38 & \textbf{-3,04} \\
    \textit{12} & 426,06 & 424,63 & \textbf{-1,43} & \textit{62} & 420,53 & 419,86 & \textbf{-0,67} \\
    \textit{13} & 427,58 & 424,70 & \textbf{-2,88} & \textit{63} & 435,26 & 431,60 & \textbf{-3,67} \\
    \textit{14} & 437,01 & 434,66 & \textbf{-2,35} & \textit{64} & 437,91 & 435,22 & \textbf{-2,69} \\
    \textit{15} & 448,93 & 444,94 & \textbf{-3,98} & \textit{65} & 435,76 & 436,06 & \textbf{0,30} \\
    \textit{16} & 427,27 & 428,27 & \textbf{1,00} & \textit{66} & 427,52 & 427,39 & \textbf{-0,13} \\
    \textit{17} & 425,86 & 426,53 & \textbf{0,67} & \textit{67} & 437,93 & 436,82 & \textbf{-1,11} \\
    \textit{18} & 433,07 & 431,37 & \textbf{-1,70} & \textit{68} & 420,70 & 422,55 & \textbf{1,86} \\
    \textit{19} & 429,31 & 428,34 & \textbf{-0,97} & \textit{69} & 433,03 & 429,61 & \textbf{-3,42} \\
    \textit{20} & 436,43 & 434,95 & \textbf{-1,48} & \textit{70} & 428,46 & 426,78 & \textbf{-1,68} \\
    \textit{21} & 443,86 & 439,46 & \textbf{-4,40} & \textit{71} & 436,85 & 435,91 & \textbf{-0,94} \\
    \textit{22} & 427,17 & 427,07 & \textbf{-0,10} & \textit{72} & 425,31 & 424,70 & \textbf{-0,61} \\
    \textit{23} & 437,70 & 435,29 & \textbf{-2,41} & \textit{73} & 426,79 & 425,98 & \textbf{-0,81} \\
    \textit{24} & 436,80 & 433,14 & \textbf{-3,66} & \textit{74} & 422,78 & 422,17 & \textbf{-0,62} \\
    \textit{25} & 428,35 & 427,11 & \textbf{-1,24} & \textit{75} & 437,71 & 438,09 & \textbf{0,38} \\
    \textit{26} & 434,41 & 431,14 & \textbf{-3,28} & \textit{76} & 423,19 & 421,06 & \textbf{-2,13} \\
    \textit{27} & 433,90 & 431,63 & \textbf{-2,27} & \textit{77} & 420,99 & 422,58 & \textbf{1,59} \\
    \textit{28} & 437,66 & 435,95 & \textbf{-1,70} & \textit{78} & 428,32 & 428,03 & \textbf{-0,29} \\
    \textit{29} & 443,21 & 440,68 & \textbf{-2,53} & \textit{79} & 439,62 & 436,70 & \textbf{-2,92} \\
    \textit{30} & 428,11 & 428,32 & \textbf{0,21} & \textit{80} & 425,97 & 425,76 & \textbf{-0,21} \\
    \textit{31} & 430,32 & 427,18 & \textbf{-3,14} & \textit{81} & 434,96 & 431,97 & \textbf{-2,99} \\
    \textit{32} & 427,81 & 427,33 & \textbf{-0,48} & \textit{82} & 427,47 & 425,60 & \textbf{-1,87} \\
    \textit{33} & 422,23 & 423,61 & \textbf{1,37} & \textit{83} & 433,79 & 432,71 & \textbf{-1,08} \\
    \textit{34} & 432,01 & 429,60 & \textbf{-2,42} & \textit{84} & 434,06 & 433,11 & \textbf{-0,95} \\
    \textit{35} & 423,96 & 425,35 & \textbf{1,39} & \textit{85} & 431,33 & 429,13 & \textbf{-2,20} \\
    \textit{36} & 435,51 & 434,16 & \textbf{-1,35} & \textit{86} & 426,43 & 423,94 & \textbf{-2,50} \\
    \textit{37} & 428,09 & 426,42 & \textbf{-1,67} & \textit{87} & 437,98 & 436,18 & \textbf{-1,80} \\
    \textit{38} & 423,34 & 423,57 & \textbf{0,23} & \textit{88} & 423,79 & 423,54 & \textbf{-0,25} \\
    \textit{39} & 444,15 & 440,84 & \textbf{-3,31} & \textit{89} & 435,79 & 434,89 & \textbf{-0,90} \\
    \textit{40} & 426,60 & 426,23 & \textbf{-0,37} & \textit{90} & 428,35 & 427,99 & \textbf{-0,36} \\
    \textit{41} & 436,68 & 435,84 & \textbf{-0,84} & \textit{91} & 425,43 & 424,45 & \textbf{-0,99} \\
    \textit{42} & 430,62 & 431,93 & \textbf{1,31} & \textit{92} & 437,60 & 436,80 & \textbf{-0,80} \\
    \textit{43} & 430,20 & 431,12 & \textbf{0,92} & \textit{93} & 434,81 & 433,76 & \textbf{-1,04} \\
    \textit{44} & 427,36 & 425,39 & \textbf{-1,97} & \textit{94} & 428,55 & 428,63 & \textbf{0,08} \\
    \textit{45} & 423,67 & 423,06 & \textbf{-0,61} & \textit{95} & 426,21 & 426,96 & \textbf{0,75} \\
    \textit{46} & 422,44 & 424,13 & \textbf{1,69} & \textit{96} & 434,48 & 431,91 & \textbf{-2,56} \\
    \textit{47} & 433,50 & 433,18 & \textbf{-0,32} & \textit{97} & 435,90 & 434,97 & \textbf{-0,93} \\
    \textit{48} & 433,44 & 430,13 & \textbf{-3,31} & \textit{98} & 417,66 & 420,48 & \textbf{2,82} \\
    \textit{49} & 425,09 & 425,83 & \textbf{0,74} & \textit{99} & 433,27 & 430,45 & \textbf{-2,81} \\
    \textit{50} & 433,02 & 430,48 & \textbf{-2,54} & \textit{100} & 431,51 & 431,51 & \textbf{0,01} \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
     \end{adjustbox}
      \caption{Total costs attributed to the 100 demand scenarios for both the deterministic and the stochastic model.}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%
```

[image]

Comment: texdoc longtable  or search this site will give thousands of examples. there is no `[h]` and you need to remove the `\centering`, `adjustbox` and `tabular`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, first and foremost get rid of `\centering`, `adjustbox`, and `tabular`.

To make the table fit inside the width of the text block, you should allow automatic line breaking in all 8 columns. I would also drop the **boldfacing** of the numbers in columns 4 and 8 and, instead, align them on their respective decimal markers. (Don't overuse bold-facing unless you deliberately want to come across as liking to shout at people...) And, to provide a bit more visual structure to header material, consider placing the units declaration on separate rows.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows of the resulting table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,eurosym}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\itshape}C *{2}{C} S[table-format=-1.2] | 
                      >{\itshape}C *{2}{C} S[table-format=-1.2] @{}}
                      
%% headers and footers:
    \hline
    Scenario & 
    Deterministic T. Costs  & 
    Stochastic T. Costs  & 
    \multicolumn{1}{C|}{\textbf{Difference} } & 
    Scenario & 
    Deterministic T. Costs  & 
    Stochastic T. Costs  & 
    \multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{\textbf{Difference} } \\
    \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8}
    & (\euro M) & (\euro M) & {(\euro M)} & 
    & (\euro M) & (\euro M) & {(\euro M)} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \hline
    \caption{Total costs attributed to the 100 demand scenarios for both the deterministic and the stochastic model.}
    \label{tab:addlabel}
    \endlastfoot
    
%% body of table
    1 & 436,05 & 433,99 & -2,06 & 51 & 435,59 & 433,18 & -2,41 \\
    2 & 437,30 & 437,71 & 0,40 & 52 & 431,33 & 430,24 & -1,10 \\
    3 & 429,85 & 430,49 & 0,65 & 53 & 440,37 & 437,46 & -2,91 \\
    4 & 426,31 & 426,69 & 0,38 & 54 & 430,01 & 426,55 & -3,46 \\
    5 & 432,58 & 432,10 & -0,47 & 55 & 431,33 & 429,88 & -1,45 \\
    6 & 439,02 & 436,87 & -2,15 & 56 & 429,63 & 427,40 & -2,23 \\
    7 & 418,62 & 420,74 & 2,12 & 57 & 432,96 & 430,70 & -2,26 \\
    8 & 443,74 & 441,88 & -1,85 & 58 & 431,46 & 431,27 & -0,19 \\
    9 & 430,93 & 429,14 & -1,79 & 59 & 421,42 & 422,11 & 0,69 \\
    10 & 425,81 & 424,64 & -1,16 & 60 & 417,78 & 419,35 & 1,57 \\
    11 & 420,18 & 422,59 & 2,41 & 61 & 437,42 & 434,38 & -3,04 \\
    12 & 426,06 & 424,63 & -1,43 & 62 & 420,53 & 419,86 & -0,67 \\
    13 & 427,58 & 424,70 & -2,88 & 63 & 435,26 & 431,60 & -3,67 \\
    14 & 437,01 & 434,66 & -2,35 & 64 & 437,91 & 435,22 & -2,69 \\
    15 & 448,93 & 444,94 & -3,98 & 65 & 435,76 & 436,06 & 0,30 \\
    16 & 427,27 & 428,27 & 1,00 & 66 & 427,52 & 427,39 & -0,13 \\
    17 & 425,86 & 426,53 & 0,67 & 67 & 437,93 & 436,82 & -1,11 \\
    18 & 433,07 & 431,37 & -1,70 & 68 & 420,70 & 422,55 & 1,86 \\
    19 & 429,31 & 428,34 & -0,97 & 69 & 433,03 & 429,61 & -3,42 \\
    20 & 436,43 & 434,95 & -1,48 & 70 & 428,46 & 426,78 & -1,68 \\
    21 & 443,86 & 439,46 & -4,40 & 71 & 436,85 & 435,91 & -0,94 \\
    22 & 427,17 & 427,07 & -0,10 & 72 & 425,31 & 424,70 & -0,61 \\
    23 & 437,70 & 435,29 & -2,41 & 73 & 426,79 & 425,98 & -0,81 \\
    24 & 436,80 & 433,14 & -3,66 & 74 & 422,78 & 422,17 & -0,62 \\
    25 & 428,35 & 427,11 & -1,24 & 75 & 437,71 & 438,09 & 0,38 \\
    26 & 434,41 & 431,14 & -3,28 & 76 & 423,19 & 421,06 & -2,13 \\
    27 & 433,90 & 431,63 & -2,27 & 77 & 420,99 & 422,58 & 1,59 \\
    28 & 437,66 & 435,95 & -1,70 & 78 & 428,32 & 428,03 & -0,29 \\
    29 & 443,21 & 440,68 & -2,53 & 79 & 439,62 & 436,70 & -2,92 \\
    30 & 428,11 & 428,32 & 0,21 & 80 & 425,97 & 425,76 & -0,21 \\
    31 & 430,32 & 427,18 & -3,14 & 81 & 434,96 & 431,97 & -2,99 \\
    32 & 427,81 & 427,33 & -0,48 & 82 & 427,47 & 425,60 & -1,87 \\
    33 & 422,23 & 423,61 & 1,37 & 83 & 433,79 & 432,71 & -1,08 \\
    34 & 432,01 & 429,60 & -2,42 & 84 & 434,06 & 433,11 & -0,95 \\
    35 & 423,96 & 425,35 & 1,39 & 85 & 431,33 & 429,13 & -2,20 \\
    36 & 435,51 & 434,16 & -1,35 & 86 & 426,43 & 423,94 & -2,50 \\
    37 & 428,09 & 426,42 & -1,67 & 87 & 437,98 & 436,18 & -1,80 \\
    38 & 423,34 & 423,57 & 0,23 & 88 & 423,79 & 423,54 & -0,25 \\
    39 & 444,15 & 440,84 & -3,31 & 89 & 435,79 & 434,89 & -0,90 \\
    40 & 426,60 & 426,23 & -0,37 & 90 & 428,35 & 427,99 & -0,36 \\
    41 & 436,68 & 435,84 & -0,84 & 91 & 425,43 & 424,45 & -0,99 \\
    42 & 430,62 & 431,93 & 1,31 & 92 & 437,60 & 436,80 & -0,80 \\
    43 & 430,20 & 431,12 & 0,92 & 93 & 434,81 & 433,76 & -1,04 \\
    44 & 427,36 & 425,39 & -1,97 & 94 & 428,55 & 428,63 & 0,08 \\
    45 & 423,67 & 423,06 & -0,61 & 95 & 426,21 & 426,96 & 0,75 \\
    46 & 422,44 & 424,13 & 1,69 & 96 & 434,48 & 431,91 & -2,56 \\
    47 & 433,50 & 433,18 & -0,32 & 97 & 435,90 & 434,97 & -0,93 \\
    48 & 433,44 & 430,13 & -3,31 & 98 & 417,66 & 420,48 & 2,82 \\
    49 & 425,09 & 425,83 & 0,74 & 99 & 433,27 & 430,45 & -2,81 \\
    50 & 433,02 & 430,48 & -2,54 & 100 & 431,51 & 431,51 & 0,01 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This really helped and I truly appreciate your tips to improve the table layout. This looks much better now!